# Blender 3.0 Undo all edit mode steps (Old Undo Behaviour)

Tags: edit-mode, object-mode

In Blender 3.0, how can I change Undo behaviour so it undoes everything done in one mode?  For example, if I make a bunch of changes in edit mode, switch to object mode, and press undo, it should undo all of the changes made instead of switching back into edit mode.

Basically how do I get old undo behaviour back?  It is absolutely critical to my workflow to be able to instantly compare before and after all changes.  Making a copy of an object before hand wouldn't work.

[image]

I need a way to do this in the same amount of time/clicks so if there is an alternative method that would also be appreciated.

This is one of many problems I have had with post 2.79 Blender but this particular issue makes the software absolutely unusable for me if there isn't a solution.

Comment: See if adding an undo history key helps: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DxW-TAXHXLA. You can also try unchecking Global Undo in Edit > Preferences on the System Tab although I've never investigated that option myself.

Comment: I don't understand, undo history already has a key.  Doesn't do what I need at all.  I need to be able to toggle back and forth with a single keypress (or holding down two keys) anything more is too much.

Global Undo is not a new option and isn't related to what I am trying to achieve.  The hover tool tip explains what it does.

Comment: In that case you're out of luck. The behaviour you're talking about disappeared when Blender 2.8 first came out approaching 3 years ago. You'll just have to get used to the current versions or stick with 2.79!

Comment: There are so many small issues and missing options as well as bigger issues like this it's a wonder that people praise Blender 3.0 so much.  3 years of people complaining and no improvements.  Really cancels out the other improvements as far as I'm concerned.